# How to do Arithmetic operations between two Ordered Dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, tuples, ordereddictionary

I am trying to do arithmetic operations between two Ordered dictionaries in Python. However I am facing the error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'collections.OrderedDict' and 'int'

Below is the Python code:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

a = {'a_key':OrderedDict([('Max_Value', [2000]), ('Min_Value', [1000])])}
b = {'b_key':OrderedDict([('Max_Value', [1000]), ('Min_Value', [50])])}
test_dict = {key: str(round(((a[key] - b.get(key, 0))/b.get(key, 0))*100,2))+'%'
              for key in a.keys()}
print(test_dict)
```

Expected result: The final outcome should be assigned to test_dict.  Here we want to find the percentage difference between 'Max_Value' of each provided above dictionaries (a, b). Similarly for 'Min_Value'.
Both 'Max_Value' and 'Min_Value' are inside OrderedDict of the dictionaries a, b.

Expected `test_dict = {'c_key': OrderedDict([('Max_Value', ['100.0%']), ('Min_Value', ['1900.0%'])])}`

Comment: You're not iterating the keys you think you are; `key in a.keys` will give `['a_key']`.

Comment: Could you help me with the solution  ?

Comment: Please edit your question with the expected result. It's too hard to guess what it should be

Comment: Hi @Nick, as suggested, I have edited the question with the expected result. I request your help here.

Comment: This is an utterly bizarre data structure. Why do `'a_key'` and `'b_key'` exist? Why are the OrderedDicts wrapped in one-entry outer dicts at all, let alone outer dicts with different keys? Why are the inner values wrapped in 1-element lists?

Comment: If this data structure is like that because you built it that way, building a simpler data structure instead would make your code much simpler. If you got this data structure already like that from some source out of your control, then putting your data into a simpler format would be a good first step.

Comment: What @user2357112 says about your data structures is all true. If this is your own structure, you could (and should) simplify to just `a = { 'Max_Value' : 2000, 'Min_Value' : 1000 }`. There is no need to use an outer key, an `OrderedDict` or a list for the values. If this is not your own structure, then you should simplify to that format before attempting to process the values. If that's the case, my suspicion is that your actual structures are far more complex that you are showing in this question...

Comment: I have found the solution by myself, on exploring a bit more. The desired solution code is provided in the answer section. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

After long struggle, I have found the desired solution by myself, on exploring a bit more. Below is the code :

```
from collections import OrderedDict
currentDict = {'a_key':OrderedDict([('Read_PMax', [21477]), ('Max_Read_P50', [92]), ('Avg_Read_P50', [92]), ('Max_Read_P90', [197]), ('Avg_Read_P90', [197])])}
baseDict = {'b_key':OrderedDict([('Read_PMax', [3325]), ('Max_Read_P50', [70]), ('Avg_Read_P50', [70]), ('Max_Read_P90', [136]), ('Avg_Read_P90', [136])])}

for key in currentDict:
 x = currentDict[key]
for key in baseDict:
 y = baseDict[key]
z = {}
w = {}
for i, (key, value) in enumerate(x.items()):
    z[key]=value
for j,(key, value) in enumerate(y.items()):
    w[key]=value
result_dict = {}
result_ordered_dict = OrderedDict(result_dict)
for key in z.keys():
    if key in w:
        result_ordered_dict[key] = [str(round(((z[key][i] - w[key][i])/w[key][i])*100,2))+'%' for i in range(len(z[key]))]
print(result_ordered_dict)
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([('Read_PMax', ['545.92%']), ('Max_Read_P50', ['31.43%']), ('Avg_Read_P50', ['31.43%']), ('Max_Read_P90', ['44.85%']), ('Avg_Read_P90', ['44.85%'])])
```